# Why does this simplifies like that?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
I don't understand how do we simplify this fraction ? How does 3^n becomes 3^(n+1) and how does 1-(1/3) becomes 2 ???
Is there a general rule for this ?

Comment: $1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$. Now multiply top and bottom by $3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an explicit path from your statement to it's simplification:
$$\frac{3^n}{ (1 - \frac{1}{3}) }
= \frac{3^n}{(\frac{3}{3} - \frac{1}{3})} 
= \frac{3^n}{(\frac{3-1}{3})}
=\frac{3^n}{(\frac{2}{3})}
= 3^n\cdot (\frac{2}{3})^{-1}
= 3^n\cdot\frac{3}{2} 
= \frac{3^n \cdot 3^1}{2} 
= \frac{3^{n+1}}{2} $$

or generally, you could try the following:

$$1\cdot\frac1{1-\frac1{x}} = \frac{x}{x}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac1{x}} = \frac{x}{x(1 -\frac{1}{x})} = \frac{x}{x -1}$$

It doesn't matter how you simplify as long as you do it right and understand how to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying it by $3/3=1$ gives you
$$\frac{3^n}{1-(1/3)}\cdot \frac{3}{3}=\frac{3^n\cdot 3}{3(1-(1/3))}=\frac{3^{n+1}}{3-1}.$$

**P.S.** Multiplying a fraction by $1$ is sometimes helpful to make it simpler. For example, since $6/6=1$,
$$\frac{2/3}{5/6}=\frac{2/3}{5/6}\cdot \frac{6}{6}=\frac{(2/3)\cdot 6}{(5/6)\cdot 6}=\frac{4}{5}.$$